# CodeIgniter 4 Error Validation Not Reading

Tags: php, forms, validation, error-handling, codeigniter-4

I'm working on a contact form with Codeigniter 4 and SQL Database. The form will submit through the button, so whenever it is clicked, it is validating, and if all of the fields are filled out, it has no trouble displaying the message and save the information to the database, but when the fields are empty, it does not display the error message, and it continues to state that the file does not exist.

Well, I'm stuck with the error message now. I'm not sure what wrong with the code. Am I missing something?

Can anybody help me with this? I appreciate all the help I can get.

**Below are my codes:**

**App/config/Routes.php**

```
$routes->get('contact', 'Contact::contact');
$routes->post('contact/save', 'Contact::save');
```

**App/Controller/Contact.php**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\ContactModel;

class Contact extends BaseController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        helper(['url', 'form']);
    }

    //CONTACT PAGE
public function contact()
{

    $data = [
        'meta_title' => 'Contact | MFD',
    ];

    return view('page_templates/contact', $data);
}

//SAVE
public function save()
{

    $validation = $this->validate([
        'name' => [
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => [
                'required' => 'Your full name is required'
            ]
        ],
        'email' => [
            'rules' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
            'errors' => [
                'required' => 'Email is required',
                'valid_email' => 'You must enter a valid email',
            ]
        ],
        'title' => [
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => [
                'required' => 'Title is required',
            ]
        ],
        'content' => [
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => [
                'required' => 'Content is required',
            ]
        ],
    ]);


    if (!$validation) {
        return view('contact', ['validation' => $this->validator]);
    } else {

        // Let's Register user into db
        $name = $this->request->getPost('name');
        $email = $this->request->getPost('email');
        $title = $this->request->getPost('title');
        $content = $this->request->getPost('content');

        $values = [
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'title' => $title,
            'content' => $content,
        ];

        $contactModel = new ContactModel();
        $query = $contactModel->insert($values);
        if ($query) {
            return redirect()->to('contact')->with('success', 'Your message are successful sent');
        } else {
            return redirect()->to('contact')->with('fail', 'Something went wrong');
        }
    }
}
```

}

**App/Views/page_templates/contact.php**

```
<form action="<?= base_url('contact/save'); ?>" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
<?= csrf_field(); ?>

<?php if (!empty(session()->getFlashdata('error'))) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?= session()->getFlashdata('error'); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if (!empty(session()->getFlashdata('success'))) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"><?= session()->getFlashdata('success'); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?= set_value('name'); ?>">
        <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'name') : '' ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" value="<?= set_value('email'); ?>">
        <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'email') : '' ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group mt-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title">
    <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'title') : '' ?></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group mt-3">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="content" rows="5" wrap="hard" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'content') : '' ?></span>
</div>

<div style="height: 10px;"></div>
<div class="text-left button">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Send Message</button>
</div>
<div style="height: 10px;"></div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have fixed the problem with my code. It's really is a small mistake or I could say careless mistake haha feel so dumb right now but all that I need to change and make it work.

Is this part: `return view('contact', ['validation' => $this->validator]);`
Instead of doing it like that I actually miss placing the file to call the view page properly so the code I only added my the folder name that is

> page_templates

and if I include it in the code it should look like this:-

`return view('page_template/contact', ['validation' => $this->validator]);`

and it works after that haha.